# How to achieve Open Closed Principle if in the future you need to add more attributes?

Tags: java, design-patterns

The problem at hand is to identify Owners based on some logic then return back an object with all of those Owners. So if client needs 3 Owner then return back an object with those 3 Owners. Example: Owner A, Owner B, Owner C. That object will then be used to add on to another object, Account, that will be send to the Database.

I was thinking of creating an OwnerIdentifier interface that classes can implement. Then have a class that has a method that takes in a variable arguments that will iterate through all the OwnerIdentifier concrete implementation and the method returns back a Map<Owner, String>. Owner is an Enum type and String is the owner alias. Once I have the map I can use that to build the model.

HOWEVER, I'm not sure if that is really the best approach...... Because I would have to then map the values in the Map to a particular field in the Account object. Then if new type of Owner are added, I would have to change the Account object...

Any suggestions would help a lot!!!

Comment: Can you code this example and point out where you see the problem in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Account shouldn't interact directly with the owner(s). There shouldn't be a parallel list of fields for Owner and Account. What is the relationship between Owner and Account. It looks like Account has a feature envy. It doesn't need to know the contents of the Map. Try encapsulating all owners in a class and see its relationship with the Account. Account should work on the structure containing the owners, not on individual owners.